# AngularJS retrieve data via AJAX before Directive runs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using AngularUI's **[uiMap](http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-map)** directives to instantiate a google map. The uiMap directive works great with hard-coded data (`{mapOptions}` and `[myMarkers]`); however I run into trouble when I retrieve this data via `$http.get()` (the directive fires before the AJAX call has finished).

Initially I was executing the GET in my `GoogleMaps` controller, but when I realised things were happening out of sequence, I moved the GET into the `uiMap` directive. I've got 2 problems with this:

1. I think this is not the correct way to do this.
2. The GET also retrieves the data for `[myMarkers]`

   - The function/directive that creates the markers is ubiquitous in that it is responsible for creating all *overlays*

So my question is, is there somewhere else in the application where I can retrieve the data (and apply it to scope) before the directive runs?

I read up on [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q), and that kind of sounds like what I want, but I'm not sure if I can do it within my controller rather than in the directive (also not sure how `$q.defer.resolve()` is any different than `$http.success()`).

**EDIT** Most of the code I'm using is copy/paste from AngularUI's doc, but here's a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/t2Nq57

## Solution

Based on [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528733/758177), I used a combination of uiMap and **[uiIf](http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-if)**:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<div
  id="map_container"
  ng-controller="GoogleMaps">

  <div ui-if="mapReady">

    <div
      ng-repeat="marker in markers"
      ui-map-marker="markers[$index]"
      ui-event="{'map-click':'openMarkerInfo(marker)'}"
    ></div>

    <div
      ui-map-info-window="myInfoWindow"
      ng-include="'infobox.html'"
    ></div>

    <div
      id="map_canvas"
      ui-map="myMap"
      ui-options="mapOptions"
    ></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**Caveat 1** uiIf cannot be in the same element that specifies the controller furnishing its condition (uiIf has higher priority than ngController, so its controller won't get set before uiIf executes).

**Caveat 2** Be sure to use the most [recent version of uiIf](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/directives/if/if.js) (the version supplied in the most recent tag, v0.3.2, is out of date). The old one has bug causing a TypeError under certain circumstances.

**Caveat 3** jQuery MUST be included before AngularJS (in index.html); else you will receive a TypeError stating that `Object [object Object] has no method 'trigger'` (or `Object [object HTMLDivElement] has no method 'trigger'` on Windows). Chrome will allow you to step into the trigger function because Chrome knows about it, but Angular does not (and Angular is throwing the error).

```
function GoogleMaps( $scope , $http )
{

  var mapDefaults = {
    center:    new google.maps.LatLng(25,-90),//centres on Gulf of Mexico
    zoom:      4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  $scope.mapOptions = {};
  $scope.mapReady = false;
  $scope.markers = [];

  $http.get('map.json').then(function mapData(response) {

    var map_data = response.data,
      user_defaults = map_data.user.defaults; //{center: [lat,lng], zoom: 15}

    $scope.mapOptions = {
      "center":    (typeof user_defaults.center !== 'undefined') ?
        new google.maps.LatLng(user_defaults.center[0],user_defaults.center[1])
        : mapDefaults.center,
      "zoom":      (typeof user_defaults.zoom !== 'undefined') ?
        parseInt(user_defaults.zoom,10)
        : mapDefaults.zoom,
      "mapTypeId": mapDefaults.mapTypeId
    };

    //working on code to populate markers object

    $scope.mapReady = true;

  });

  // straight from sample on http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-map
  $scope.addMarker = function($event) { … };
  $scope.openMarkerInfo = function(marker) { … };
  $scope.setMarkerPosition = function(marker, lat, lng) { … };

}//GoogleMaps{}
```

<s>**Drawback** uiMap does not currently support rendering makers on domready. I'm looking into an alternative version of uiMapMarker suggested in this [GitHub issue / comment](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/issues/173#issuecomment-8765849).</s>

Solution to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14617167/758177

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/0CMdW3?p=preview

Comment: Can you post the controller and service code.  I have an idea, but want to make sure what you are currently doing.

Comment: @BenFelda added a plunk to my question

Comment: Is the hard coded data that worked the same as you are returning in `map_data.locations`?  Sorry if its a dumb question, but it looks like it should work.

Comment: @BenFelda: no, the data will be retrieved from a database (I just use the json file to simulate the response).

Comment: Have you tried pasting the data that comes back from this service statically into the array just to validate the data?

Comment: @BenFelda: yes both within the callback of `$http` (ignoring the returned data and hard-coding to the `mapOptions` object) and before the callback. Hard-coding it prior to the GET allows the directive to function normally; hard-coding it within the GET's callback produces a TypeError (`mapOptions` is empty when the directive tries to use it). But the data itself is valid and in the proper format for the directive (and the Google Maps API).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could just delay execution of ui-map until your data is loaded.

HTML:

```
<div ui-if="loadingIsDone">
  <div ui-map="myMap" ui-options="myOpts"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$http.get('/mapdata').then(function(response) {
  $scope.myOpts = response.data;
  $scope.loadingIsDone = true;
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but then the map never appears. I checked `$scope.mapReady` after the `.then()`, and it's value is `true`. I've updated the plunk, but the version in plunk complains about a TypeError that I don't get locally (and I copy/pasted entire files from my local, only changing the filename of angular-ui's app.js to angular_ui.js to avoid a naming collision).

Comment: found the source of the `TypeError`. For some reason the values I assign to `$scope.mapOptions` within the `.then()` do not stick (`mapOptions` is empty after/outside the .`then()`).

Comment: I think `ui-if` doesn't work (or doesn't work as expected): I've wrapped my `ui-map` div in a `ui-if` and it still apears in the DOM but doesn't (ever) appear, and angular still tries to process the uiMap directive (which is what it would seem `ui-if` should stop it doing).

Comment: `ui-if` is now part of the Angular core as `ngIf`.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, what you can do is have your directive get set up, start the load and finish in the success. I'm assuming you want to load one piece of data for all instances of your directive. So here's some psuedo-code for how you might want to attack this:

```
app.directive('myDelayedDirective', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

  //store the data so you don't load it twice.
  var directiveData,
      //declare a variable for you promise.
      dataPromise;

  //set up a promise that will be used to load the data
  function loadData(){ 

     //if we already have a promise, just return that 
     //so it doesn't run twice.
     if(dataPromise) {
       return dataPromise;
     }

     var deferred = $q.defer();
     dataPromise = deferred.promise;

     if(directiveData) {
        //if we already have data, return that.
        deferred.resolve(directiveData);
     }else{    
        $http.get('/Load/Some/Data'))
          .success(function(data) {
              directiveData = data;
              deferred.resolve(directiveData);
          })
          .error(function() {
              deferred.reject('Failed to load data');
          });
     }
     return dataPromise;
  }

  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     template: '<div>' + 
          '<span ng-hide="data">Loading...</span>' +
          '<div ng-show="data">{{data}}</div>' + 
        '</div>',
     link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
         //load the data, or check if it's loaded and apply it.
         loadData().then(function(data) {
             //success! set your scope values and 
             // do whatever dom/plugin stuff you need to do here.
             // an $apply() may be necessary in some cases.
             scope.data = data;
         }, function() {
             //failure! update something to show failure.
             // again, $apply() may be necessary.
             scope.data = 'ERROR: failed to load data.';
         })
     }
  }
}]);
```

Anyhow, I hope that helps.

Comment: I would prefer to not do the GET in the directive (I don't think it belongs there?), but also doing so is a problem because scope is isolated to that directive, and the markers directive needs some of the data retrieved in the initial GET.

Comment: You could easily break that GET out into a service, and it would be the same thing. For simplicity's sake I didn't do that in my example... if you have another directive that requires the same data, then you would take all of the logic with the GET and its promise and put that in a service, then have both directives call the loadData on that service.

Comment: I like that better. But I still run into the problem that the directive responsible for creating the markers is also the directive responsible for creating infowindows and area overlays. So sticking a Service call into that directive is not applicable in 2/3 of what it does.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will help without seeing code, but I ran into this same issue when I was creating my `$scope.markers` object inside the `$http.success` function.  I ended up creating the `$scope.markers = []` before the `$http` function, and inside the `.success` function, I populated the `$scope.markers` array with the return data.

So the $scope object was bound while the directive was compiling, and updated when the data returned.

[UPDATE SUGGESTION]

Have you tried taking advantage `resolve` in your route?

```
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when(
        '/',{
          templateUrl: 'main.html',
          controller: Main,
          resolve: {
               data: function(httpService){
                   return httpService.get()
               }
          }
      }).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
  }
```

I usually put my $http requests in a service, but you could call the $http right from your route:

```
App.factory('httpService'), function($http){
     return {
       get: function(){
           $http.get(url)
       }
    }
});
```

Then, in your controller, inject `data` and set your `$scope` items to the data.

Comment: This sounds strange that updating a reference works but declaring a new one does not. Can you open a bug ticket citing this thread/example on AngularUI?

Comment: @ProLoser My answer has more to do with Angular in general, and binding in the controller when using $http.  My thoughts are that the issue has little to do with AngularUI.

Comment: Now that I see the plunk, my current answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @BenFelda I added the 2 $scope property instantiations before the GET per your suggestion (it wasn't there to begin with)

Comment: Won't that inject the data into the `Main` controller (instead of the `GoogleMaps` controller)?

Comment: @jacob Sorry, I did overlook that.  You are correct, the `Main` controller would be the one receiving the model, however I am curious where Main even gets used?  Oh well.  I like Andy's answer, didn't think of that.  I hope you got it working.

Comment: @BenFelda, I did, thanks! I'll post the solution later today. Trying to get the markers to show up onload (which AngularUI uiMap doesn't natively support, so re-writing the uiMarkers directive / trying to use https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/issues/173#issuecomment-8765849). Thanks tho! Good to know about `resolve:` :)

Comment: @BenFelda, btw Main is used for sending and receiving WebSocket messages/pushes (and a handful of other very small things that don't belong anywhere else). As I flush out the app, Main might become erroneous (the small/bespoke things may become large enough to warrant their own controller).