# Angular-UI $scope.myMap is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to `$watch` `myMap` but it never fires. I've narrowed it down to having used `ui-if` (if I remove the ui-if, `$scope.myMap` is the proper google maps object). However I need to keep the ui-if in order to get `ui-map` to wait for my AJAX/Db query to finish.

<s>Why isn't myMap being added to scope (and how do I get it to)?</s>

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qs2FaW)**

**Edit** I see from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/issues/266#issuecomment-10463822) that ui-if creates its own scope. So how do I access its scope / wherever `myMap` now lives? Also, why does ui-if create a new scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a model on your `GoogleMaps` controller:

```
$scope.model = {};
```

Pass the model as reference to the `ui-map` directive:

```
ui-map="model.myMap"
```

Watch for changes:

```
$scope.$watch('model.myMap', function(map){
    ...
}
```

This way you avoid the creation of the `myMap` property inside the `ui-if` scope.

Also check this [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) for more information on the prototypical inheritance of scopes.

Comment: Ahah! Now the myMap object is available (and so is the locations object); everything seems to be going swimmingly, but then the markers don't appear on the map: http://plnkr.co/edit/khlQVB I tried inspecting the google-map object of one that had markers to compare with mine (to see if my map object has registered them), but I couldn't figure out which property holds marker data (thought it might be in `overlayMapTypes` or `qc`.

Comment: figured it out! instead of setting `var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng( $scope.locations[i][0],$scope.locations[i][1]);` I had to hold each `$scope.locations[i][#]` in its own parameter, and THEN run `new google.maps.LatLng`.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify where you want the object to be stored, including on a parent scope:

```
ui-map="$parent.myMap"
```

Although this is considered to be semi unreliable (as any number of directives may create additional scope layers) and you may want to consider setting it to a property of an object.

Comment: ohh, that's good to know (that I can specify storing it on the parent scope that way). Thanks! I think I would prefer setting it to a property of an object. @bmleite 's answer seem to be exactly that but strangely the markers don't appear on the map.