# Execute http post request before directive

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, function

I have a post request in angularjs that get's a string pattern from my backend:

```
var tabledata = "";
$http.post("lib/action.php", {monsters: $scope.getMonsters}).success(function(data) {   
    tabledata = data;   //Assign the pattern

}).error(function(data) { console.log("error"); });
```

This pattern is then used in a function call below:

```
$scope.result = makeTableFrom(tabledata); //Call the function to build the table based on the pattern
```

The thing I want to accomplish is that I want my directive to execute AFTER that the post request has been completed, because now when I run my application, the tabledata is just an empty string, and therefor, my makeTableFrom function is returning an empty result.

Here is my directive:

```
gameApp.directive('mapActivity', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('tabledata', function() {

             angular.element('.click#1').addClass('dotted').html($("<img src='images/dot.png'>"));          
                var j = null;
                for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'lib/terrain.php',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data: {i: i},
                        success: function(data) {
                            var randomRuta = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                            angular.element('.click#'+randomRuta).addClass('monster').html($("<img src='images/blackdot.png' title='"+data+"'>"));                  
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(thrownError); }
                    });
                    j=i;
                }  
                angular.element('.click').click(function() {
                    if(angular.element(this).hasClass('monster'))
                    {
                        if(confirm('Vill du anfalla monster?'))
                        {
                            alert("Du vann");
                            angular.element('.click.monster'+j).empty();
                            angular.element('.click.monster').removeClass('monster'+j);

                            angular.element('.click.dotted').empty();
                            angular.element('.click.dotted').removeClass('dotted');
                            angular.element(this).addClass('dotted');
                            angular.element('.click.dotted').html($('<img src="images/dot.png">'));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        angular.element('.click.dotted').empty();
                        angular.element('.click.dotted').removeClass('dotted');

                        if(!angular.element(this).hasClass('dotted'))
                        {
                            angular.element(this).addClass('dotted');
                            angular.element(this).html($('<img src="images/dot.png">'));
                        }
                    }
                });
            });                     
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527583/angularjs-retrieve-data-via-ajax-before-directive-runs

Comment: @MohammadShahrouri: I don't know how to accomplish this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here what you have to do:
- add new variable to your `$scope` :`$scope.resultLoaded = false;`
- change the post success to this:

```
success(function(data) {   
 $scope.result = makeTableFrom(data);
 $scope.resultLoaded = true; 
}
```

-in your html you use it as follows:

```
<div ng-if='resultLoaded'>
  <table map-activity>...
</div>
```

Comment: @MohammedShahrouri That don't work. Have a look at this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/UfmePF7V, console.log(tabledata) is just an empty string. It's supposed to hold the data from the $http.post

Comment: that is because you call `console.log(tabledata);` and `$scope.result = makeTableFrom(tabledata);` before the http success function is called. I have modified my answer to reflect the correct change